# XCode "Too few items in teams" error when refreshing provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to build my apps. I've installed the provisioning profiles that my team has set up. I've installed my developer certificate and the WWDR certificate. But when I refresh my provisioning profile library it throws this error:

[image]

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I seem to have the exact same issue, and you seem to be the only other person in the world to have it... I also have no clue.

Comment: Seconded. "Too few items in Property/teams/Entity/Developer" is mine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [too few items in teams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171278/too-few-items-in-teams)

Comment: None of the answers on this page are working for me. I'm an independent developer (no team) and just purchased a Mac Developer account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like I had two accounts for apple like most people: 1) email address account and 2) just apple user ID login.

When you sign up for an iOS developer account, only one account gets approved as an iOS developer. It doesn't matter if those two accounts are merged and linked inside apple profile, only one gets approved. You can check this by logging into both accounts separately to their developer website. One account will say you are a member and another will say pay up the fee to become iOS developer.

The problem is that your keychain already stored one of apple id credentials from the past... and you probably signed up for apple iOS developer program using the other apple login. Xcode automatically gets keychain's previously stored credential for 'Teams' section and since that account from keychain was not activated for the iOS developer account, it's complaining that no one is a valid developer in 'Teams'.

To solve this,

1. delete any, all apple related stuff from your keychain login.
2. revoke all the problematic profiles, certs, etc from apple website.
3. just redo provisioning process only using iOS developer approved apple login.
4. From XCode Organizer's Teams section, click 'refresh' icon at the bottom and follow direction.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me when I use Apple Developer account which **does not have valid iOS developer certificate**. The certificate is either expired or never bought in the first place.

Once I log in with the valid iOS Developer account, the problem no longer appears.

Comment: The key part being - does not have valid iOS dev certificate. This would probably be the most popular reason for the warning.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was a simple logout from iTunes and Mac App Store. I was loged with an different Apple ID. This Apple ID is different from my Apple ID that I'm using for iOS Program.

Answer (score 1):

I got the message too:
"Too few items in Property/teams/Entity/Developer"

It works now, after adding my account (which is connected with the macbook in itunes and which I used in Xcode) to an "Developer" under "Peoples" at https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#iPhoneDev

Give it a try.

Comment: This gives me an "access denied" message, even when I'm logged in. Could be the page no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Please reference:
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Provisioning Profile Refresh Troubleshooting:

If you are receiving the error message:

**Too few items in Teams**

Perform the steps below:

1. Open Keychain Access > Passwords category.
2. Delete the entries for daw.apple.com and daw2.apple.com
3. Retry the Provisioning Profile Refresh process.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note if somebody from Mac Develop program lands here:

I'm brand new to Apple development, so, maybe this is a common knowledge, but I didn't ran across.

Signed up for Mac Developer program, not iOS, and tried to "Refresh from Developer Portal" with exact same error: "Too few items in teams." Tried all the steps above and elsewhere, with no success.

Ended up calling their support to only find out that this particular functionality doesn't work with Mac Dev only (no iOS Dev) membership profiles. So, manual download/import is the solution as tech on the phone told me that it looks for iOS teams, doesn't find it and errors out.

Hope this helps & saves a couple of hours of frustration for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I still encountered the same issue after following the other answers on this page. Here is what I needed to do to get things working.

Make sure that you have fully accepted the invitation email to join the Apple Developer program. Your account admin can verify your status through the management panel.

1. Click the link inside the "Please verify your email address" email
2. Click the "submit" button to finish registration

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer.apple.com. In the upper right menu area, select "Member Center." Once in the Member Center, select "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles."

Verify your accounts have not expired; or if new to the program (or renewal) that the order has been processed.