# too few items in teams

Tags: ios, certificate, refresh, provisioning, organizer

I am trying to set up a new machine with XCode and my developer account and keep running into the following error while trying to refresh provisioning profiles from the Organizer:

> Too few items in Property/teams/Entity/Developer

I have followed all of the suggestions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616493/xcode-too-few-items-in-teams-error-when-refreshing-provisioning-profiles), to no avail.

It seems like it's a problem with multiple/incorrect identities in the keychain, but I have not been able to fix it thus far, and there seems to be very little info on this issue in the wild.

I have tried all of the following:

1. Deleting all of development-related certificates in my keychain
2. Revoking/reissuing the development certificate via iOS dev center.
3. Logging out of all other Apple-related services (iTunes, App Store, etc).
4. Reinstalling XCode via App Store.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: this is not really an answer, but for anyone it might help, this error also occurs if your developer profile is not installed on the machine.

Comment: How do I install a developer profile on my machine? (None of the answers on this page have worked for me.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Was able to solve this just now by following some advice from another developer forum.

This worked for me:

1. Log out of all services requiring an Apple ID (iTunes, App Store, etc)
2. Delete any existing developer identity certificates from your keychain.
3. Open keychain and delete all keys containing "daw2.apple.com" and "daw.apple.com" from all keychains.
4. Close and reopen XCode.
5. Open organizer and click refresh. You will be prompted to enter your account information. Make sure to enter the Apple ID associated with your developer account. Check the box "store in keychain".
6. It should fetch the certificates and provisioning profiles from your developer account and the error should be gone!

Credit to Ronald Lee for this answer.

Comment: You should self-select this as the appropriate answer, so as to mark this question answered.

Comment: Thanks, I meant too, but SO wouldn't let me do it immediately, and of course, I forgot to come back and mark it as answered.

Comment: How can I identify a "developer identity certificate"? Are they named specially in Keychain? I don't see any certificates that are named that way.

Answer (score 12):

This stuff is just sooooo frustrating. Not sure if it will help but I snapshoted what I have in the KeyChain. When you see a disclosure triangle it means there is a Key under the certificate.

[image]
[image: Second Shot]

Comment: Thanks for the snapshots! I agree this stuff is terribly frustrating and convoluted.

Comment: WOW - amazing - someone just down voted my answer! What possible reason could they have??? Not that the -2 hurts, but the intent does! I took a lot of my time to take these snapshots and upload them... Weird!

Comment: I'm sure it didn't take thát long to take two screenshots...

Comment: Yeah, you're right @RobinKanters - I should just have passed on this thread and not done anything to try and help. Yeah, that's the ticket - I'll try and remember not to do it again. Shame on me since I didn't have the exact answer at my fingertips... [PS I had to edit each shot to block out my specific info, but yeah, it didn't take an hour, so I should not complain]

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way:

1. Open your keychain
2. Press "All the elements" in the "Category"
3. Now select "login" in the keychain Tab
4. type in the search bar "daw.apple.com"
5. delete all the results of this search.
6. Restart Xcode
7. Open the organizer
8. refresh the "provisioning profiles" page
9. Insert your username and password.

Answer (score 1):

@mutexmark is right:)

BTW, here is the Apple doc:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Provisioning Profile Refresh Troubleshooting:

If you are receiving the error message:

**Too few items in Teams**

Perform the steps below:

1. Open Keychain Access > Passwords category.
2. Delete the entries for daw.apple.com and daw2.apple.com
3. Retry the Provisioning Profile Refresh process.

Answer (score 0):

I still encountered the same issue after following the other answers on this page. Here is what I needed to do to get things working.

Make sure that you have fully accepted the invitation email to join the Apple Developer program. Your account admin can verify your status through the management panel.

1. Click the link inside the "Please verify your email address" email
2. Click the "submit" button to finish registration