# XCode Organizer recognizes my old developer profile

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, xcode4.3

Back when I was still in school, I was granted a student license by my school so that students could develop iOS apps and install it on their devices. That was like 2 years ago. I just updated XCode to 4.4 today and I am having problem running my apps on my device I was getting the infamous "Valid signing identity not found message"

I tried to look for a solution and decided to just re-start the entire process (get new certificate, mobile provision etc etc). It seems like the workflow to do this has changed and now everything is done through XCode. I tried to request new provision profile through XCode and I see that I am still a member of my old university. I tried to request for a new certificate and it tells me that the admin of the group needs to approve it.

I am wondering... how does XCode get all this information? I want to change my profile because it is not using the right profile (for example, on member center I see that my license will expire next month but on XCode I see it expires 7/13/2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

1) try using this search text: [ios] [xcode] 'Keychain Access'
Some of the posts have huge numbers of up votes, look at those.

2) Try this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12171278/1633251) and look for originators answer at bottom - that might work for you.

3) Its possible that in addition to Keychain items, there are preferences involved here. One of the posts that comes up when running 1) describes how to move or delete other Xcode files. Unfortunately just removing Xcode does nothing to the preferences it leaves around.