# "Too few items in Property/teams/Entity/Developer" message in XCode

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

Ok, so I have created a very simple App in XCode 4.6.2 and I want to test it on my iPad. So I plug my iPad into my Mac, and whenever I click "Add to Portal" in the Organizer I get this message:

> Too few items in Property/teams/Entity/Developer

Ive followed all the suggestions I can [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171278/too-few-items-in-teams), but no matter what keys I delete off my keychain, and no matter how many times I reinstall XCode the problem wont go away.

I am thinking maybe I am not deleting the right certificates? I have removed all the ones I could find that were mentioned, and later I removed the ones I could find that had "Developer" in them but still no joy.

I feel very uncomfortable removing keys and certificates, as I am new to developing on a Mac and I have no idea what keys/certificates I am removing, or whether I can re-obtain these keys/certificates later on.

To help me better understand this problem, can anybody explain to me:

- What that error message actually means?
- What causes this problem, so I can avoid it in the future.
- How I can solve this problem?
- Is there anything I can permanently mess up by removing keys/certificates? Or can everything be re-obtained and/or fixed?

Comment: it seems no body can help on this one. Ive had further problems with this convoluted process here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572208/certificate-identity-iphone-developer-appears-more-than-once-in-the-keychain