# Too few items in Property/teams/Entity/Developer error

Tags: xcode4

i got this error while refreshing Provisioning Profiles and i tried all solutions i can reach but non of them solved my problem. if anyone has an idea to solve this please tell me !!!

Comment: Please list *what* you've tried, in order to avoid duplication of effort.

Comment: For example.  How about this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616493/xcode-too-few-items-in-teams-error-when-refreshing-provisioning-profiles

Comment: what is the difference between email address account and  just apple user ID login ?

Comment: i do delete every thing in keychain and that not help

Comment: OK, so what else have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171278/too-few-items-in-teams
they are almost the same solution

Comment: if you see that the first solution you gave to me is a good one please can you follow it with me, i cant understand what to do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35815/discussion-between-ahmad-d-and-trojanfoe)

Comment: @Abdullah Shafique can you help me ?